# Unbuffered version of Process.BeginOutputReadLine method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, io, io-redirection

Some console applications, such a plink, may not print a new line character after printing important information (eg. "Store key in cache? (y/n)"). Is there a built in way to asynchronously read from a programs stdout that does not wait for new lines? If not, is creating a separate thread to read characters synchronously a good idea?

Comment: You can just call the process' StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead() yourself.  Don't get your hopes up, interactive console mode apps are usually pretty cranky to redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Read()` instead of `ReadLine()`. A simple asynchronous implementation would look something like this:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Process process = ...; // init as appropriate, including redirection of stdout

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    var _ = ConsumeReader(process.StandardOutput, sb);
}

async Task ConsumeReader(TextReader reader, StringBuilder sb)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int cch;

    while ((cch = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(buffer, 0, cch);
    }
}
```

The above simply copies the text to a `StringBuilder`. Presumably in your own scenario you would do something else, like parse it and respond to prompts, that sort of thing. Given the lack of a code example, I can't be more specific than that.

This example also ignores the `Task` returned from the async method. That may be fine in your case, or you might want to give the variable a better name than `_` and eventually wait on the `Task` at some later point. Use it as you see fit.